# system freeze (nvidia?)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 21.10, external-monitor

I have installed a new Ubuntu 21.10 (dual boot with windows 10) on
Dell Precision 3561 - Intel Core i7-11800H - RAM 16GB (also having swap partition of approx. 20 GB, though installed on other NVME).
Grafic: NVIDIA T600, 4GB using it with nvidia-driver-510 (btw. had boot issues at the beginning with the default xserver-xorg-video-nouveau).

Also I use an external monitor via HDMI (hann spree, 32'').

I was away from computer for a while, so it went to sleep (?). When I logged in, only the primary screen was enabled, I used `super+p` to enable the second screen, it worked, but the output was scaled strange. Then everything froze. Only mouse was alive. No keyboard combination could do anything. After hard restart, now it woks alright. Also, I was again away for a while and could use the computer as usual.

I set general font size in (`settings > accessibility > Large Text`) before the issue.

Looking for this issue there were some issues mentioned with NVIDIA... Maybe any thoughts, to prevent this in the future?

Comment: Could it be that the computer's HDD got unplugged or something? Or was the cpu overheating?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it is possible that an HDD was plugged in into the usb hub while it happend. CPU should not be overheating as I did not do any exhaustive CPU jobs.

Comment: Again, after I was a while away, only the laptop screen was alive. But this time when I changed to "external only" nothing bad happend. In the background some files were copied from HDD to NVMe.